# Empty Line error while sending GET request from fiddler

Tags: tcp, get, fiddler

I wrote following line in Fiddler Composer>Raw tab and pressed execute,

```
GET /api.php/phy/3 HTTP/1.1\r\nHOST: maz4579.esy.es:80\r\n\r\n
```

but it says that **the HTTP request is incomplete. Please ensure that there is single empty line after headers.**

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler's Composer doesn't attempt to decode \r\n into a carriage-return line-feed pair. Instead, just hit the enter key after each line.